# angular + jasmine: mock a directive

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller that "feeds" a directive with data:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <my-drtv data="ctrl.data"></my-drtv>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function MyCtrl(){
    this.data = "dummy";
}

function myDrtv() {
   return {
      template:'<div>{{myData}}</div>'
      scope:{
        data:'='
      },
      link:function(scope){
        scope.myData = scope.data.toUpperCase();
      }
   }
}
```

I need to mock the directive in order to verify that the controller has passed the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

This is a bad approch.

Since I want to test my controller, I should test it's output (`ctrl.data`) directly.